"response" body "access_token" property must be a non-empty string
I have Next.js app with next-auth using GitHub provider. I created a new app on GitHub OAuth page and got Client ID and Client Secret. Then I followed exact steps from next-auth docs to set it up:

https://authjs.dev/getting-started/installation
https://authjs.dev/getting-started/authentication/oauth

The problem is that I'm getting OperationProcessingError: "response" body "access_token" property must be a non-empty string when I click "Signin with GitHub" in my app.
Firstly, I get redirected to GitHub, then I allow access to my GitHub info, then redirected back, then error happens.
I've tried recreating GitHub OAuth app and going through the same steps from next-auth docs, but the error persists.
GitHub OAuth app dashboard shows that new user is created.
Package versions:

"next": "14.2.3"
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.17"

auth.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const { signIn, signOut, auth, handlers } = NextAuth({
    providers: [GitHub],
});

middleware.js
export { auth as middleware } from "@/auth";

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import { handlers } from "@/auth";
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

components/sign-in.jsx
import { signIn } from "@/auth";

export function SignIn() {
    return (
        <form
            action={async () => {
                "use server";
                await signIn("github");
            }}
        >
            <button type="submit">Signin with GitHub</button>
        </form>
    );
}


Please edit your question and include your code

I've got exactly the same problem. I'm pretty new to Auth.js and just following the documentation it doesn't seem working without extra research.

Check to make sure you have the correct AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET in your config. I had the same error, turned out I had some misconfiguration in that variable, fixed it up and it logs in fine.
